# Not able to get more then one results with images in WPF datagrid from Mysql Database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, datagrid

With this code i am able to get one image from Mysql database in C# in WPF. But i have a table in database that contaon all countries's names and their
flag etc. When i query to select many or all countries folling error occur 
"Cannot set the initializing state more than once" at this line "bi.BeginInit()".
Thanks in advance.

```
    string co = null;
    string na = null;
    string le = null;
    string gn = null;
    string A = "pak";
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Code,Name,LifeExpectancy,GNP,flg from country where Name REGEXP '" + A + "'", connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {

            co = dataReader["Code"].ToString();
            na = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
            le = dataReader["LifeExpectancy"].ToString();
            gn = dataReader["GNP"].ToString();
            Byte[] bindata = (Byte[])dataReader["flg"];
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
            strm.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);
            strm.Position = 0;
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm); 
            bi.BeginInit();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bi.StreamSource = ms; 
            bi.EndInit();
            dt.Rows.Add(co, na, le, gn, bi);
            dataGridCustomers.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because you are creating the BitmapImage outside of the loop. So Once you get in the loop it keeps trying to set the initializing state on the same image.  As your error states you can't do this.  What you need to do is create a new BitmapImage on each iteration.  Which can be accomplished by moving the line

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
```

To the inside of the loop.  Unless there is a specific reason you are initializing it where you are.

```
string co = null;
string na = null;
string le = null;
string gn = null;
string A = "pak";

try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Code,Name,LifeExpectancy,GNP,flg from country where Name REGEXP '" + A + "'", connection);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

        co = dataReader["Code"].ToString();
        na = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
        le = dataReader["LifeExpectancy"].ToString();
        gn = dataReader["GNP"].ToString();
        Byte[] bindata = (Byte[])dataReader["flg"];
        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
        strm.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);
        strm.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm); 
        bi.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bi.StreamSource = ms; 
        bi.EndInit();
        dt.Rows.Add(co, na, le, gn, bi);
        dataGridCustomers.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

---

EDIT: In the code above, the `System.Drawing.Image` is entirely redundant. You should directly create the BitmapImage from the byte array like this:

```
var bindata = (byte[])dataReader["flg"];
var bi = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bindata))
{
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bi.StreamSource = stream;
    bi.EndInit();
}
```

Comment: i have initialized it outside the while loop and try-cache but error is same.

Comment: It's because when the loop hits the second iteration on bi.BeginInit();  you are trying to initialize it when it's already been initialized.  Create a new instance of the BitMapImage inside your loop for each iteration (as outlined in my answer) to eliminate this issue.

Comment: Now i have moved this line inside the loop now error is "parameter is not valid" on this line "img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);"

Comment: Then the question here has been answered.   The new error would need to be a new question although I'm sure it's already out there.   Is the data that you are receiving back valid?  Place a breakpoint and confirm that it's what you're expecting to have returned from the database.

Comment: No problem.  If you are satisfied with this answer please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @DailyLifeVideos Please see the edited answer for a less complicated way to create the BitmapImage.

Comment: @Clemens thank you it help. its simple. but i did't understand this line  bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

Comment: It's necessary when you want to close the stream right after EndInit, which you usually want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks